# Is there any method other than .each() function to collect information from input fields into an array, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a form like;

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="myfield[]" class="qwerty" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="myfield[]" class="qwerty" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="myfield[]" class="qwerty" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="myfield[]" class="qwerty" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="myfield[]" class="qwerty" /><br />
  <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="clickme" />
</form>
```

and I collect the information into an array like;

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  var myArray = [];
  $('.qwerty').each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    var item = $.trim(current.val());
    if(item != ""){
      myArray.push(item);
    }
  });
});
```

This creates a loop. Is there any other simple / efficient method for doing the same?

Comment: `item != ""` - red flag

Comment: @ŠimeVidas just to ignore empty form fields

Comment: I'd tell you about JavaScript type coercion but I don't want to ruin New Year's Day for you `:p`. Just use `!==` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.map()` along with `.get()` to achieve what you need.

Try,

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {

  var myArray =  $('.qwerty').map(function(){
     var item = $.trim($(this).val());
     if(item !== ''){
       return $.trim($(this).val());
     }
    }
  }).get();

});
```

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to know more about `.map()`

**Edit:**

Use the following code to find the number of valid inputs.

```
$('.qwerty').filter(function(){
     return ($.trim($(this).val()) !== '');
}).length
```

Comment: this works bro :) . A little more help, is there any way to get the number of valid inputs?

Comment: @blasteralfredΨ Yes its a easy task like this. Just tell what condition may tell a text box is valid.?

Comment: `if(item !== '')` makes it valid

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for make request from this form then may be

```
$('#myform').serialize()
```

can help you